# Fetch data from a database from two different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using C#(asp.net). I have two tables(data and details) in a same database.

Table "data"

```
id | chap | unit |
  ----------------
  1| chap1|unit1 |
  2| chap2|unit2 |
  3| chap3|unit3 |
```

Table "details"

```
id| code| num |
----------------
 1|abc  |2    |
 2|efg  |3    |
 3|hij  |1    |
```

Now I want to fetch a value from "num" where code="efg" (in table "details"). And use the same value (3) to fetch data from table "data" by id. I am using this code.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(*** ...... *****); 
       OleDbCommand cmd;
       OleDbDataReader reader;
        String query = String.Format("select num from details where code="efg");
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int num = int.Parse(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());

        query = String.Format("select chap from data where id={0}",num);
         cmd = new OleDbCommand("select lesson from data where id=3", conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        Label1.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

But it shows error. It shows "No data exists for the row/column."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT d.chap, d.unit
FROM data d INNER JOIN details de
    ON d.id = de.num
WHERE de.code = 'efg'
```

or

```
SELECT d.chap, d.unit
FROM data d INNER JOIN details de
    ON d.id = de.num
   AND de.code = 'efg'
```

More: if you're using SQL-Server, use [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in place of `OleDbConnection`.
More: don't format your query joining strings, numbers, dates and so on; use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so you don't have to worry about types and formatting!!

Comment: Actually i m using Microsoft access for database, that's why I am using 'OleDbConnection'. Sorry I mistakely tag sql server.

Comment: @Viktor: did my answer solved your problem? If so you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM data INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT num FROM details WHERE code='efg') det
ON data.id = det.num
```

Comment: This query is exactly the same as both of the two you provided in your answer, when it comes to execution, due to the Query Optimizer. Non-correlated is the keyword here. In fact, we have provided three different ways to make SQL perform the exact same task (execution plan can confirm this). Downvoter probably doesn't have a clue about how the optimizer works.

Comment: alex, what I wanted to show you is not that query itself is wrong, nor that query optmizer does not translate it in my same query; I'm sure you understand that a newbie like OP must be shown simpler and *default* way to write queries, because he is not able to understand what an execution plan is or how query optiomizer works :) Do you agree with me?